# how to refrence a nested class value by array value

Tags: php, stdclass

I think the best way to explain my question is to give an example.  Say I have the following object.

```
$data=new stdClass;
$data->test=new stdClass;
$data->test->test2=6;
$data->s=array('b',6,7);
```

I want to know how I can read or change any value in the object given the key value as an array.

I know the below won't work:

```
function doSomething($inputArray1,$inputArray2) {
    $data[  $inputArray1   ]; //6
    $data[  $inputArray2   ]=4; //was array('b',6,7);
}

//someone else provided
doSomething( array('test','test2')  , array('s')  );
```

Changed to make clear that I do not know the values of the array personally so using 
`$data->test->test2;` to get the 6 like I normally would won't work.  Also do not know the array length.

Comment: You want to change the objects array value? `$data->s[2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$parts=array('test','test2');


$ref=&$data;
foreach($parts as $part) {
    if (is_array($ref)) {
        $ref=&$ref[$part]; //refrence next level if array
    } else {
        $ref=&$ref->$part; //refrence next level if object
    }
}
echo $ref; //show value refrenced by array
$ref=4; //change value refrenced by array(surprised this works instead of making $ref=4 and breaking the refrence)
unset($ref); //get rid of refrence to prevent accidental setting.  Thanks @mpyw
```

Comment: Execution `unset($ref);` is strongly recommended after your task is finished.

Comment: thanks @mpyw I am sure that would have caused me all kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments, you need to access the object/arrays as intended.
Their notations are as follows;

- Object: `->`
- Array: `[]`

So, taking your `$data` array you've generated, you'd have to access the object/array combination as such:

```
echo $data->s[2];
```

<sup>[*Example/Demo*](https://www.tehplayground.com/vtutWlzMXZQYXmYr)</sup>

And if you were to access the initial `test/test2` itteration (which is set as an object *(`->`)*), then you need to access it as an object:

```
echo $data->test->test2;
```

Comment: that is how I would normally do it if I knew the values in the array.  I do not.